# Snakemake specifying configuration parameter from nested config.yaml file on the command line

Tags: yaml, snakemake

Say I have a config.yaml file such as follows

```
results: "results/"
reference_database: "data/zymogen_alignment_file.fasta"

basecall:
    perform_basecall: True
    configuration: "dna_r9.4.1_450bps_hac.cfg"
```

I can access all the parameters in my Snakefile, such as `config["results"]`, `config["basecall"]["perform_basecall"]`, etc.

I can override the `results` and `reference_database` parameter easily
`snakemake --cores all --config results="/my/new/results/path" reference_database="/my/new/reference/database"`

However, I can't seem to be able to override the parameters under `basecall`. I have tried the following
`snakemake --cores all --config basecall["perform_basecall"]=False`

But this results in the error: `Invalid config definition: Config entry must start with a valid identifier.`

Is it possible to override parameters in a nested configuration file?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JSON object syntax. In this specific case, something like

```bash
snakemake -j all --config basecall='{perform_basecall: False}'
```

Testing this, it seems to retain the rest of the object (i.e., the `configuration` value) and just overrides the `perform_basecall` value.

Comment: How about double (and possibly more) nested entries?

Comment: @pawelru Can you provide a concrete example? JSON grammar fully supports such expressions, e.g., `'{obj1: {key1: value1, key2: value2}}'`.

Comment: The example is as follows:
```
level1:
 level2:
  level3:
   item1: 1
   item2: 2
```
And the question is how to modify `level1.level2.level3.item2` value in the `snakemake` call.

Comment: @pawelru Have you tried `--config level1='{level2: {level3: {item2: 2}}}'`? If that doesn't work, then consider posting a new question with what you tried and how it fails. Feel free to leave a link to the new question here and I'll have a look.